# How to run a local python script from django project hosted on aws?

Tags: python, django

I have a requirement to run a local python script which takes arguements and will run on local windows computer from python code hosted on aws.

Comment: Have you tried: os.system("python something.py") module to execute script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you simply need to find a way for the two of them to communicate without opening huge security holes.

My suggestion would be a message queue (rabbit MQ, amazon SQS).  The aws application writes jobs to the message queue and a local script runs the worker which is waiting for messages to be written to the queue for it to pick up.

Comment: Can you give me any link or any code example to refer?.I have to host this script on local and my django code deployed on aws should access this local script..I tried to host this code on local computer and made static ip of local computer so that i can access from aws but now my big concern is security ,so if there is any secure way please let me know..

Comment: Please research the technologies I referenced.  Celery is a library you can use to interface to Rabbit MQ. Good luck.